# Nswag Generate a C# Interface from openapi yaml

Tags: c#, msbuild, openapi, nswag, openapi.net

Given the following example OpenAPI spec YAML, how can I ensure that that the `Greeting` component is generated as a C# `interface`, instead of a `class`, when using `NSwag.MSBuild` version `13.15.10` ?

I have tried both `x-implements: ['com.example.ICustomInterface']` and `x-interface: true` but neither work. Can not find any documentation.

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Simple API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /hello:
    get:
      summary: Get a greeting
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  message:
                    type: string
                    description: A greeting message
                    example: Hello, World!
components:
  schemas:
    Greeting:
      type: object
      properties:
        message:
          type: string
          description: A greeting message
```